# When function returns object, is there a shorthand to assign property x to variable y?

Tags: typescript

I would like to assign property `body` to variable `html`.

```js
import got from "got"

(async () => {
  const { body } = await got("http://example.com"); // What is this shorthand called?
  const html = body; // Trying to eliminate this line.
  console.log(html);
})()
```

Comment: `const { body: html } = await ...`

Comment: Maybe this: `const html = (await got("http://example.com")).body`

Comment: @Lennholm that works... but why? Somehow, I would have expected this to store the value of `html` in property `body`. Do you know what this shorthand is called? Would like to learn more about it looking at the docs.

Comment: @ShamPooSham That also works. Thanks!

Comment: @sunknudsen here you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names). Thanks Aleksey L.!

```
import got from "got"

(async () => {
  const { body: html } = await got("http://example.com");
  console.log(html);
})()
```